# Why doesn't the progress bar progress?

Tags: java

Following function is called to move the progress bar but I don't know why it doesn't move till other process just works on.

```
private void startProgressBar() {
    signInProgressBar.setMinimum(0);
    signInProgressBar.setMaximum(10);
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int p = 1;
            while(!loginCompleted) {
                signInProgressBar.setValue(p);
                //System.out.println(p);
                p++;
                try {Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception exc) {}
            }                    
        }
    };
    new Thread(r,"progress_bar_thread").start();
}
```

Snippet that calls `startProgressBar` :

```
        startProgressBar(); // CALL
        String username = usernameTextField.getText();
        String password = new String(passwordField.getPassword());
        Openfire server = new Openfire();
        boolean isConnected = server.connect(username,password);
        if(isConnected) {
            // Stash the username and password
            User user = new User();
            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setPassword(password);

            // Stop the progress bar
            loginCompleted = true;

            // Display the next window
            UserGUI blab = new UserGUI();
            blab.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose(); // Dispose off the login window
        }
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Could this be the issue signInProgressBar.setValue(5) in Runnable's run method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this stuff:

```
    Openfire server = new Openfire();
    boolean isConnected = server.connect(username,password);
    if(isConnected) {
        // Stash the username and password
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);

        // Stop the progress bar
        loginCompleted = true;
        // ....
```

... should be done on a background thread, especially connecting and interacting with the server, else you'll be tying up the Swing event thread and with it your entire GUI. Also use a SwingWorker for your background thread and just set its value which the JProgressBar can easily follow via a PropertyChangeListener.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't appear to adjust the progress bar at all:

```
signInProgressBar.setValue(5);  // <-- in your while loop
```

This just continually sets the bar's position to `5`, which appears to be about 50% on your scale. Perhaps if you are unsure of the length of your task, you should make your progress bar [indeterminate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate%28boolean%29)?

You should also be using the EDT to adjust the progress bar with `setValue()`. See the [Concurrency in Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) for more details.

Comment: that was by mistake..I have removed the statement that sets the value to 5

Comment: @saplingPro I'm referring to the statement in your `while` loop.

Comment: @Hover Fair enough, I had typed "scrollbar" by mistake. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!loginCompleted) {
            signInProgressBar.setValue(5);
            //System.out.println(p);
            p++;
            try {Thread.sleep(5000);}catch(Exception exc) {}
        }
```

You made a small mistake signInProgressBar.setValue(5); should be ignInProgressBar.setValue(p);

The current code when starts will generate a empty bar then immidieatly will set it to 50% , there is no statement that progresses it after login is complete.

Answer (score -2):

You may need `repaint` and `invalidate`.

try

```
signInProgressBar.invalidate();
signInProgressBar.repaint();
```

and why you set always 5 for `signInProgressBar.setValue`

Comment: This is never needed for this type of situation. These methods are required when a container has components added or removed, not when a JProgressBar's value is adjusted.